# Regarding Frame extraction from the HD Video with the help of time(in the form of seconds as shown below) of the Video position

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using **EmguCV 3.1.0** library, by using this i am fetching the frames as shown below...

**_capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.PosMsec, 17.567);**

**Image"<"Bgr, Byte">" frame = captureData.QueryFrame().ToImage"<"Bgr, Byte">"();**

**pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap();**

in the above piece of code 17.567 is the time of the video frame. i am fetching the video frame with the help of time and we are displaying on picturebox control.
so here SetCaptureProperty function taking long time to fetch frame from the HD video. due to that the performance got reduced....

Please ignore the double quotes in source code...

can you please help in this...
thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you are short on information here. Are you capturing from a file or a live HD video stream? Give me a few more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have given a video file as input to capture object